# linking php to html variable

Tags: php, html

I have a variable in HTML that i am trying to make the output of my_locations.PHP file.

my PHP file outputs into a browser from SQL:

```
["Address - Name", "Lat", "Long", 1],
["Address - Name", "Lat", "Long", 2],...
```

i need the variable to insert this into my code with the same format as above.

My HTML vaiable is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var locations = [["Address - Name", "Lat", "Long", 1],
                  ["Address - Name", "Lat", "Long", 2], ];
```

Does someone know what i need to do to get this to work?

Comment: there are NO variables in HTML...

Comment: You could parse the HTML Page with a PHP HTML Parser and extract the contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var locations = <?php echo json_encode($myarray) ?>;
```